# Ruby Regex replace /abcdef/abcdef to /abcdef

Tags: ruby, regex

To replace routes which doesnt match beginning value of the variable path comparing the values in the variable str.

```
path = '/qqqq/rrrr'
str = %w|abcd efgh ijkl mnop \n|
path.gsub(/\w+/) { |rep| str.include?(rep) ? rep : 'unknown' }
```

> Input > path = /abcd  Output > /abcd
>
> Input > path = /efgh  Output > /efgh
>
> Input > path = /abcd/efgh  Output > /unknown
>
> Input > path = /xxxx Output > /unknown
>
> Input > path = /xxxx/yyyy  Output > /unknown
>
> Input > path = /xxxx/abcd  Output > /unknown

Is there a equivalent for include in regex?

Comment: To clarify, you want to remove all parts of a path that are not found in `str`, and you also want to condense multiple subsequent matches into one? So `/abdc/qqqq/rrrr/efgh/ssss` would become `/abdc/unknown/efgh/unknown`?

Comment: Please define "routes". Are you sure you don't mean `sub` rather than `gsub`? Also, `str` is not the best name for an array. ;-)

Comment: unmatched values of str in the any part of the path should condense result to /unknown. 
input: /abdc/qqqq/rrrr/efgh/ssss
output: /unknown

Comment: What do you mean by beginning? It looks like an unknown string anywhere is triggering a match?

Comment: Input: /abdc/qqqq/rrrr/efgh/ssss  Output: /unknown
Input: /sdfgfg/adcd/efegh Output: /unknown
Input: /abcd/efgh Output:/unknown

Input: /abcd  Output:/abcd
Input: /efgh Output:/efgh

Comment: In view of your next-to-last comment I would have suggested `arr = %w| abcd efgh ijkl mnop \n |; path = "/abcd/qqqq/rrrr/efgh/ssss"; path.gsub(/\w+/) { |rep| arr.include?(rep) ? rep : 'unknown' } #=> "/abcd/unknown/unknown/efgh/unknown"`, assuming you meant `path` begins `"/abcd"`, not `"abdc"`. You previous, comment, however, tells me that I (and no doubt others) do not understand the question.

Comment: Oh, of course I meant `abcd`. It seems to me that any path that is not in that list in its entirety should become `unknown`. So now it becomes a simple verbatim comparison of strings, you don't need a regex for that...

Comment: May i was not clear. I have edited the post to make it more clear. when the beginning of the path doesnt match a value in str should results in unknown. I had given the sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: Readers: if you've had trouble understanding the question, I can help. In a comment on my now-deleted answer, I asked the OP, "Are you saying that the return value should simply be `str.include?(path[1..-1]) ? path : '/unknown'`?, to which he replied, "Yes. Does it possible on regex?". "Yes" tells you what is being asked. As to using a regex, see how @mudasobwa makes use of `Regexp::union`.

Comment: How is your title related to your question? I don't see any `/abcdef/abcdef` pattern which becomes `/abcdef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = %w|abcd efgh ijkl mnop|
paths = %w|/abcd /efgh /abcd/efgh /xxxx /xxxx/yyyy /xxxx/abcd|
paths.map { |path| path[%r|\A/(?:#{Regexp.union(str)})/?\z|] || '/unknown' }
#⇒ ["/abcd", "/efgh", "/unknown", "/unknown", "/unknown", "/unknown"]
```

Regexp is: `\A` for the beginning of the string, followed by a slash, followed by a regular expression built as a union of possibilities, followed by maybe a single slash, followed by the end of string.

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for "/abcd":String

Comment: No way. You have an error somewhere. The code above perfectly works.

Comment: _paths_ is plural. I did not convert anything, but you might want to _at least read_ my code in the answer I provided.

Comment: when i use paths your code works. But my value for paths is different. paths = "/abcd" not %w|/abcd|. This is causes the problem to map. Any workaround to convert string to %w

Comment: Then you are to update my code for your needs. This is not a service to write a code for you for free and I could not care less about _your particular_ need. I have provided an answer that could be valuable for the future visitors.

Comment: Thanks.. Appreciate your valuable comments.

Comment: @CarySwoveland surely it’s not; I just took this opportunity to promote a use of `Regexp#union`, which definitely deserves a wider audience than it has now :)

Comment: I misspoke about a regex being inappropriate here. +5 for understanding the question, +5 for your solution. What a time-waster this question has been!

Answer (score 0):

Using gsub! should do the trick:

```
path.
  gsub(/\w+/) { |rep| str.include?(rep) ? rep : 'unknown' }.
  sub!("/unknown", "")
```

Comment: You are not using `gsub!` anywhere in your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

If any path that does not match one of options entirely should be converted:

```
result = subject.gsub(
    /\A                     # Match from the start of the string
    (?!                     # Assert that this doesn't match:
     \/                     # a slash
     (abcd|efgh|ijkl|mnop)  # followed by one of the allowed paths
     \z                     # that makes up the entire string
    )                       # (End of lookahead assertion)
    .*                      # Match anything/x, '/unknown')
```

But you don't need a regex for that.

Comment: path should entirely match with one of the options. if not matched convert to '/unknown'. See the edited question for more.

Comment: That's what this regex does. Did you test it, and it didn't work as expected?